# Hive - clustered by and sorted by returns unsorted result

Tags: sorting, hive, clustered-index, buckets

I created a table with buckets, clustered by, and sorted by like this:

```
set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
set mapred.reduce.tasks = 32;

create table my_table
(  
    a          string
   , b          string
   , c          int
)
clustered by (a, b) sorted by (a, b) into 32 buckets
row FORMAT delimited fields TERMINATED BY ','
stored AS parquet
tblproperties ('parquet.compress'='SNAPPY');
```

The data was inserted like this:

```
insert into table my_table select * from old_table;
```

When I query:

```
select * from my_table limit 100;
```

I get unsorted results. Does it mean that the table is not sorted?
Will sorted merge join on this table work if I'll join this table with other table on `a` and `b`?

BDW: 
When I query the old_table (for which the insert into included distribute by and sort by) like this: `select * from old_table limit 100;` I get sorted results

Answer (score 0):

While you have set Hive to enforce bucketing, you need to also set Hive to enforce sorting before inserting the data into your new table, "my_table". Try this:

```
hive.enforce.sorting=true;
```

Then you should get sorted results in the new table.